# Ajax MVC Updating a Dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to do a look up with Ajax and a dropdown list, The user enters a postcode in a text box, then clicks search.
From here I want to populate a dropdown list, with the values coming from the database,
The action is in a separate controller :-

```
public ActionResult Search(string Pcode)
{
return Json(new[] {
    new { value = '1', text = "text 1" },
    new { value = '2', text = "text 2" },
    new { value = '3', text = "text 3" }
});
}
```

My HTML:

```
  Pcode:- @Html.TextBox("GPPOST")
  GP Practice:
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patient.GPSurgery)
  <br/>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Patient.GPSurgery     Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"-- Select GP --")
                GP :  <input type="button" id="SearchPcode" value="Search">
```

And finally the Ajax:

```
        $(function () {
            $('#SearchPcode').click(function () {
                // get the new value
                var value = $(this).val();
                // and send it as AJAX request to the action
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/GP_Practices/Search',   //'<%= Url.Action("Search", "GP_Practices") %>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { pcode: value },
                    success: function (result) {
                        // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the dropdown list with 
                        // The JSON values returned from the controller action
                        var GPNames = $('#Patient.GPSurgery');
                        GPNames.empty();
                        $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                            alert(item.text);
                        });

                        $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                            GPNames.append(
                                $('<option/>', {
                                    value: item.value,
                                    text: item.text
                                }));
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

When I run the code I do get the Json results back,  (which I can see in the alert box).

My 2 problems are:
1)I cannot seem to pass the value from the text box Html.TextBox("GPPOST")

2)The Dropdown list is not refreshing with the new values.

Comment: Do you get any alerts?

Comment: Hi yeah I do get the 3 alerts with text 1 , text 2 and text 3 - so the call to the controller is fine. But I cant get the drop down to update, or pass the value from the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)I cannot seem to pass the value from the text box Html.TextBox("GPPOST")

That's because your Javascript passes `pcode`, yet your controller expects `Pcode` (**casing matters**).

**Also** as  Ehsan Sajjad mentions, you're not sending the value of the textbox, but this unearths a bigger problem: **You're binding two fields to the same model property**, you can't do that. You'll have to use a separate field for your dropdown and your search input.

> 2)The Dropdown list is not refreshing with the new values.

That's because your jQuery selector is incorrect:

```
var GPNames = $('#Patient_GPSurgery');
```

Comment: _"casing matters"_. No it does not. The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive.

Comment: @StephenMuecke He's not model binding, his parameter is a single `string`. The names must match (including casing).

Comment: Nope. OP is posting to an `ActionResult` method with parameter `string Pcode`. The `DefaultModelBinder` is responsible for binding it. `data: { pcode: value },` or `data: { pCOdE: value },` work just the same.

Comment: Also there is no element `$('#Patient.GPSurgery');` - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Patient.GPSurgery` will create `<select name="Patient.GPSurgery" id="Patient_GPSurgery" >` so it needs to be `$('#Patient_GPSurgery');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good point about the selector, I've updated to reflect. I didn't realise the model binder was case insensitive, thanks for that.

Comment: The real problems are (1) `var value = $(this).val();` returns `"Search"` (the `value` attribute of the button, not the textbox with `id="GPPOST"`), and (2) `GPNames.empty();` throws an error because `GPNames` is undefined (incorrect selector) as does `GPNames.append()`. But even if the correct selector was used, it would still result in an error because `$('#Patient_GPSurgery')` would be the textbox, not the dropdownlist because of the invalid html